# Can I use the the animation/action from one bone on another bone on a later time?

Tags: animation, bones, linked-data, nla-editor

I have a animated bone : translation on Y with ipo keys,

can I use this exact data (linked) with another bone - starting on a later frame?

and how?

Or how is a proper workflow for this...?

maybe nla?

Comment: Is the other bone that you want to use exactly (x) across from the first bone? you can use an x mirror.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, when you keyframe a bone an action will be created. To assign the same action to another bone just switch to the *Dope Sheet* set *Action Editor* mode and select the action.

[image]

In the NLA you can arrange the actions e.g.

[image]

Comment: I see you have used different Armatures but I have just one... can you explain how to bind the action to the other bone...

Comment: @Blenerd Hm, you wrote 'another bone'. You can set the action in the NLA by adding an action strip. In the example I simply selected the other bone and selected the action in the action editor. In the NLA I just moved one strip to create the time offset.

Comment: yes, I have two (and more) bones in one armature ... i am confused that you can use the action just for a completely differnet armature but no for just another bone inside the same armature - its kind of useless - or how to

Comment: @Blenerd Think of a walk cycle you want to reuse for different characters, this would be obviously useful.

Comment: maybe I need to split my armature up into parts, I'll try ...

Comment: @Blenerd You could also ask another question and show your armature and explain a bit more detailed what you want to achieve.