# How to mirror the action constraints from the left foot bones to the right ones

Tags: armature, bones, constraints, mirror

I'm trying to mirror the action constraints and the associated keyframes from the left foot to the right one of my character but I don't know what's the right way to do that. I tried to redo the action constraints from the beginning for the right foot,but it didn't work. Infact,it creates two different constraining actions variables : the first one that I created for the left foot it works great and it is called `"MCH_toeCurl"` but when I create a new series of keyframes for the right foot,the action constraining variable is called `"MCH_toeCurl.001"` and it is able to move the right foot only when I scale up the `"CTRL_toe.R"` bone,it does not work when I scale down the same control bone.

On the final rigged version of `Piero`,the author used one only constraining actions variable that's called `"MCH_toeCurl"` and he used it to make work the left and the right foot. I tried to look for a tutorial that explains what to do in this situation,but I didn't find it. I added a short video to explain.

PS : Maybe I found the solution here :

https://blenderartists.org/forum/archive/index.php/t-257031.html

where `Revolt_randy` says :

Copy pose/paste mirrored pose? Select all bones in left hand with keyframes on them, on each keyframe - copy pose, paste mirrored pose (with auto keying turned on, keyframes will be inserted for you). Then you will have to change the name of the controller bones in the action constraint. Common pitfall is not having the bone's axis correct, resulting in the paste mirrored pose to cause the bones to rotate in strange ways.

PS 2 : maybe this is the solution :

[Can I use the the animation/action from one bone on another bone on a later time?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/24011/can-i-use-the-the-animation-action-from-one-bone-on-another-bone-on-a-later-time)

---> problem is that I don't know exactly ​what to do...can you give me a more detailed explanations or even better,a tutorial ? thanks.

[----> this is what happens to the right foot bones](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B_vrhf_PTNauLTlUNE8yd1RCOUk/view)​

Comment: You don't have to use action constraint, you can use Transformation constraint. This saves you some actions in the rig and simplifies things.

Comment: can you post a little example to help me understand what I should do ? thanks.